# Json Parsing with Lib Gson in Java

Tags: json, gson

I'm trying to parse this json captured through an API of my client:

```
[
  {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 7,
      "total_pages": 11,
      "entries": 100,
      "total_entries": 1007
    },
    "logical_numbers": [
      {
        "logical_number": {
          "id": 50095,
          "number": "524103650",
          "app_version_ids": [
            1427,
            1230,
            847
          ],
          "created_by": 1510,
          "created_via": "interface",
          "group_id": 526,
          "created_at": "2016-03-21T15:54:30.670-03:00",
          "updated_at": "2016-03-21T15:54:30.682-03:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "logical_number": {
          "id": 44593,
          "number": "524103627",
          "app_version_ids": [
            1427,
            1230,
            847
          ],
          "created_by": 1510,
          "created_via": "interface",
          "group_id": 526,
          "created_at": "2016-02-26T10:02:20.561-03:00",
          "updated_at": "2016-02-26T10:02:20.608-03:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here are the classes I created for this work:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Pagination[] pagination = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input1.json"), Pagination[].class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(pagination));
    }
}

class Pagination {
    Long page;
    Long total_pages;
    Long entries;
    Long total_entries;
    ArrayList<LogicalNumbers> logicals;
}

class LogicalNumbers {
    int id;
    String number;
    ArrayList<String> app_version_ids = new ArrayList<>();
    String created_by;
    String created_via;
    String group_id;
    String created_at;
    String updated_at;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following result:

> [{}]

I'm not succeeding in the parsings. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring the json I found the reason of the empty deseralization...
you have two small problems...
1st one:
your json is actually an array with one object that contains a **Pagination**
object and a logical **numbers array**

[image]

2nd: the POJO description of the json schema is not correct..

after a while I found a solution:

## Try:

```
class Foo {
private Pagination pagination;
private List<LogicalNumbers> logical_numbers;
}

class Pagination {
Long page;
Long total_pages;
Long entries;
Long total_entries;
}

class LogicalNumbers {
Ln logical_number;

}

class Ln {
int id;
String number;
List<String> app_version_ids = new ArrayList<>();
String created_by;
String created_via;
String group_id;
String created_at;
String updated_at;
}
```

and then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Foo[] pagination = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input1.json"), Foo[].class);
// Pagination[] pagination = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input1.json"), Pagination[].class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(pagination));
}
```

Comment: you are welcome, please dont forget to vote up/accept the answer if the post resolve your question